# SwiftUI 1.0: Core Data Error - Data isn't saved

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to add a object to Core Date but I get the following errors:

> 2020-12-04 22:02:56.371981+0100 IntervallTraining[4873:1925709] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x281188900> ,  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x281188900> ,  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
>
> 2020-12-04 22:02:56.372211+0100 IntervallTraining[4873:1925709] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
> CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)

The structure of my core data model:

I have the entity Workout with 10 attributes. One of the attributes have the type "Category" which is also a core data entity with three attributes.

When I try the code without the attribute "category" it works perfectly.

Does anyone has a solution. Thanks in advance.

PS: I use the AppDelegate to create my persistenContainer

Comment: Maybe add some code?

Comment: You can't use Core Data entities as attributes of another entity.  That is what relationships are for.